# Evernote URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, evernote

Does anybody know, what is the URL Scheme for Evernote? I need it to open my 'Evernote' App from a button I have created. If there is not an URL Scheme for Evernote, can anybody please tell me how should I do to open my 'Evernote' App from a button?

Answer (score 5):

[Here's Evernote's documentation on their URL scheme](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php), and [a discussion thread about how the URL is constructed](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/40001-ios-54-note-links-feature-completion-request/).

In a nutshell, you're going to create an `evernote://` URL and open it.

Comment: I have done it, just like you said: 
@"evernote://"
But when I click the button that opens my 'Evernote' App, immediately when the Evernote App appears it closes instantly. So in other word, my button doesn't open my Evernote App with that URL Scheme.
I don't know what to do.

Comment: Interestingly, I found that app links did not work from Chrome but did from Firefox Focus (on Android Oreo).  If future readers of this answer get stuck and cannot get any link to trigger, I would recommend trying another browser just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Try "evernote://root". This is copied from action list.

Mike